# Why am I getting 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, renderpartial

Why am I getting the following error?

> `nil` is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

I think the error may relate to the tutorial I'm following is using Rails 3.2 while I'm using Rails 4.

Here is the model code:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @text_shout = TextShout.new
    @photo_shout = PhotoShout.new
    @shouts = current_user.shouts
  end
end

class PhotoShoutsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    content = build_content
    shout = current_user.shouts.build(content: content)
    if shout.save
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash.alert = "Could not shout."
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end

  private
  def build_content
    PhotoShout.new(photo_shout_parameters)
  end

  def photo_shout_parameters
    params.require(:photo_shout).permit(:image)
  end
end
```

Here is the view code with the error occurring on the _shout.html partial

```
# app/view/dashboards/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @text_shout do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_field :body, placeholder: 'Shout content here' %>
   <%= form.submit 'Shout' %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @photo_shout do |form| %>
   <%= form.file_field :image %>
   <%= form.submit 'Shout' %>
<% end %>

<%= render @shouts %>

# app/view/shouts/_shout.html.erb
<%= div_for shout do %>
  <%= link_to shout.user.username, shout.user %>
  shouted
                                 +---------------------------------+
  <%= render shout.content %> <--| ERROR "nil' is not an Active "  |
                                 | "Model-compatible object"       |
                                 +---------------------------------+
  <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(shout.created_at), shout %>
<% end %>

# app/views/photo_shouts/_photo_shout.html.erb
<%= image_tag photo_shout.image.url(:shout) %>
```

Comment: on what line you are getting this error??

Comment: <%= render shout.content %>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you have existing records in your database that don't have content associated to them. This happens because you went from a non-polymorphic setup to a polymorphic setup. What you need to do is look for shouts that are missing content_type and content_id and remove them from the database. Once those are removed, it could be useful to add

validates_associated :content

to your Shout model to ensure data in the future doesn't end up "corrupting" your database.

Comment: In rails console I deleted all the shouts with Shout.destroy_all. >>>Shout.destroy_all  => [#<Shout id: 11, user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-11-05 17:57:31", updated_at: "2013-11-05 17:57:31", content_type: "PhotoShout", content_id: nil>]. I also added the validation but the photoshout is not saving and I am being redirected to the dashboard with flash message "could not shout."

Comment: So it seems like you might not be passing the content value down correcty. Could you try pasting your log when you're making a request?

Comment: My log was giving me imagemagick errors.  So, I "brew uninstall imagemagick" because I had an outdated version and reinstalled it. I also put Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" in my Rails config/environment/development.rb . Thank You.

Comment: If you are following this in Rails 4 rather than the recommended 3.X then you will hit this problem around 30 min mark of 3rd video (which is where I ran into it). In short instead of: extend ActiveModel::Naming you want to include ActiveModel::Model - or see my full answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Including ActiveModel into plain Ruby objects

The Thoughtbot Intermediate tutorial in Rails 4 has few complications, but, one problem comes in adding ActiveModel functionality into a plain Ruby object. I see this on the Week 3 Video around the half hour mark while the tutor (AKA Mr Halogenandtoast) is extracting the timeline object.

Instead of: extend ActiveModel::Naming you want to **include ActiveModel::Model** - Rails 4 change to make it easier to work with plain objects.

```
class Timeline
  include ActiveModel::Model
...
...
```

[For Thoughtbot learn subscribers there's a link to the discussion.](http://forum.thoughtbot.com/t/week-3-extend-activemodel-naming-not-working/927/7) Strong parameters were the other problem for this otherwise excellent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`@shouts = current_user.shouts` on this line your `@shouts` is setting as `nil`

check for `current_user.shouts`, it must be returning as nil

**Edit**:
instead try this

> `<%= render @shouts.content %>`

Comment: from which action is `shout.html.erb` partial rendered??

Comment: I have a polymorphic association where shouts contains the content_id and content_type. The DashboardsController show contains @shouts = current_user.shouts. Did I answer your questions?

Comment: i tried <%= render @shouts.content %> and it gave me--- undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass

Comment: By the way, I appreciate your help.

Comment: no you are not calling the partial from your `show.html.erb` file,coz `@shout` is defined in `show` action.See it is simple thing, you need to set the `@shout` variable from the controller in the same action in which you are calling the partial

Answer (score 1):

I found this error in my development log, which was the issue all along. I was super confused for a little while.

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing <Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>
```

Looks like the fix is just to run `brew update` (optional) and `brew install imagemagick`, for anyone else looking for the fix to the thoughtbot tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Installing imagemagick will solve the issue.

Check requirements section in Readme

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#requirements
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor

Answer (score 0):

`brew install imagemagick` did the trick.

I was having a similar error, even after cleaning out the database of any old records.  The PhotoShout was being saved into the database with `content_id: nil`, which was clearly the source of the problem.

I cleaned out the database once more, ran `brew install imagemagick` and the photos began uploading successfully.